# My mat4 translate function not working correctly

Tags: c++

Usually I use cglm in my projects but now I decided to make my own math to avoid a bit of bloat. My mat4 functions for rotation and scale are working correctly but my translation function is not.

The typedef for my m4 type is just:

```
typedef float m4[4][4]
```

The translate function is:

```
void m4_translate(m4 model, v2 v, float z_index, m4 dest){
    m4 translation_mat;
    m4_identity(translation_mat, 1.0f);
    translation_mat[0][3] = v.x;
    translation_mat[1][3] = v.y;
    translation_mat[2][3] = z_index;
    m4_mul(model, translation_mat, dest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the translation index. Not create a identity matrix, set translation values and so on. In the next step your rendering engine will translate the coordinates